# Servlet ERROR JDBC ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, servlets, jdbc

I have a login page.
User is supplying username and pass.
Then login sevlet is checking if the user exists in the Db if not then username and password is send to the ldap server and if user exists on the ldap server then new user is created on the local mySql DB.

Servlet is working ok I can see that pass and usename is send to the TOMCAT. Problem is when I try to connect to mySQL database. 
Here is the code:

```
package database;
import java.sql.*;


public class DbConnect {

    /**
     * Static method for user authentication
     * Test method
     * @param username - Username already striped from illigal chars (XSS safe)
     * @param pass - password
     */
    public static void connect(String username,String pass)//Consider changing void to boolean
    {
        Connection con;
        PreparedStatement st;
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            //Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");//Loading DB Driver
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Open a connection
        //  Database credentials
        final String USER = "root";
        final String PASS = "";
        final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/imf_jsp";
        try {
             con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
             st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user WHERE signum = ? AND pass_hash = ?"); //Find user with given username & pass
             st.setString(1, username);//Bind param (Should prevent SQL Injection? Not sure but it is working in PHP with PDO)
             st.setString(2, pass);//Bind param (Should prevent SQL Injection? Not sure but it is working in PHP with PDO)
             st.execute();//statemant execution
             System.out.println("In Database?: " + st);//If not then check in LDAP
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
```

Here is the StackTrace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at database.DbConnect.connect(DbConnect.java:20)
at servlets.loginServlet.doPost(loginServlet.java:43)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am using ojdbc5.jar It is in WEB-INF/lib added to bildpath
What is possibly wrong?
With PHP I have no problem connecting to the mySQL database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loading the wrong JDBC driver. [MySQLs JDBC](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,42473,280627) driver is com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. Your code should look like:

```
package database;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;


public class DbConnect {

    /**
     * Static method for user authentication
     * Test method
     * @param username - Username already striped from illigal chars (XSS safe)
     * @param pass - password
     */
    public static void connect(String username,String pass)//Consider changing void to boolean
    {
        Connection con;
        PreparedStatement st;
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            //Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");//Loading DB Driver
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Open a connection
        //  Database credentials
        final String USER = "root";
        final String PASS = "";
        final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/imf_jsp";
        try {
             con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
             st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user WHERE signum = ? AND pass_hash = ?"); //Find user with given username & pass
             st.setString(1, username);//Bind param (Should prevent SQL Injection? Not sure but it is working in PHP with PDO)
             st.setString(2, pass);//Bind param (Should prevent SQL Injection? Not sure but it is working in PHP with PDO)
             st.execute();//statemant execution
             System.out.println("In Database?: " + st.toString());//If not then check in LDAP
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Still the same problem :(

Comment: Do I have to download different JAR?

Comment: With a modern JDBC driver you don't even need to load it yourself, it just needs to be on the classpath.

Comment: Yes, @SzymonKrawczyk, or http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.31/mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar

Answer (score 0):

i could have commented but i dont't have the right for it so i am writing this as answer.
You are saying that you are trying to connect with mySql database. but jar name and class name is for oracle. you need mysql jdbc jar.